How is "One doubt about Dirac notation " a homework like question?
The question:
One doubt about Dirac notation
I quote from how do I ask homework questions on physics stack exchange


Ask about the specific concept that gives you trouble

We expect you to narrow down the problem to the particular concept
that's giving you trouble and ask about that specifically. [...]
The best way to produce a focused, specific question is to show your
work. [...]

So according to this guideline, asking homework-like questions is fine as long as you

ask about a specific concept
show your work

In my opinion, both these conditions are met. In fact, I would say this question is an excellent example of a good question. It showcases both these conditions and it also showcases a common misconception that a lot of students would benefit from.
< rant >
This question (my question, not the one I linked) is actually not really a question, but more a call to pay attention to behaviour like this. Physics stack exchange can be very unwelcoming to newcomers and closing questions unjustly is not only unwelcoming, but actively hinders the results that this site was built for. This question, that a lot of people can benefit from, can now no longer receive new answers with possible valuable insights. That's why I will vote to reopen.
</ rant>

I would encourage you to read the first full sentence of the HW policy you linked, as it completely disagrees with your assessment of the policy.

That said, could there be a valid question therein? Sure, I believe that just about every closed HW question could be re-written to be more conceptual. The problem is that changing the question would make it a drastic edit which should only be done by OP. And since it has an answer already, the changes have to be such that the existing answer is not invalidated. This is probably a fairly difficult task for OP.

you seem to have overlooked the other type of question and the description in the closure reason...

@KyleKanos Do you mean "It's not enough to just show your work and ask where you went wrong. If you just need someone to check your work, you can always seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on."?

@KyleKanos If the reason is that it's a check-my-work-question, then I would still have to disagree. It's a question about the concept "how does the Hermitian conjugate work together with bra-ket notation". The policy is meant to prevent people from blindly pasting homework questions in the hope that other people will do it for them. I think this question does not fit under this class. It it did, it would invalidate a lot of good questions on this site.

@BioPhysicist I think it also does not fit under check-my-work. If you read carefully, OP explains his line of reasoning. OP then asks if their line of reasoning is correct. It's not a line of homework, it's a part of OP's chain of thought.

I would like to stress that I don't mean to be defensive. I just disagree with the reasons for closing. I want to keep the discussion constructive.

The “homework” tag is also an umbrella for “check-my-work”, and this is clearly check my work.

I mean: how can “ I really can't see where my mistake is. :( “ not be please “please check my work”.

now admittedly the question presents a common error and I think the question can be salvaged if reformatted and reorganized, but I’m sorry to say I see no reason as to why, in its current formulation, it does not qualify as check-my-work.

FWIW, this question is one that I would say was closed without people thinking much about the post


How is "One doubt about Dirac notation " a homework like question?

This is a common misreading of the closure reason, both by those whose questions are closed as well as the users trying to evaluate the closure reason. The entire reason currently given is (emphasis mine)

Homework-like questions and check-my-work questions are considered off-topic here, particularly when asking about specific computations instead of underlying physics concepts. Homework questions can be on-topic when they are useful to a broader audience. Note that answers to homework questions with complete solutions may be deleted!

There is a misconception that when this closure reason is applied there are PSE users who see a question an think, "this looks like homework, it has to be closed". And maybe there are people like that, but as someone who voted to close this question, I will say I didn't think of closure like that in this case, and I try not to do that in any other cases as well. In fact, when I see a "homework-like question", I am always hopeful that it will still be a good example of an excellent PSE post, since I really do enjoy helping people learn physics by focusing on key physical concepts.
In this case, I voted to close because of what I put in bold in the quoted closure reason above. This is clearly a "check my work" post. The post is not asking about an underlying physics concept here. Even the only answer given is just "here is the step you got wrong", and then some math to show the correct step. Of course, a post should not be evaluated by the answers it has, but the type of answer can be indicative of what the post is about.

So according to this guideline, asking homework-like questions is fine as long as you

ask about a specific concept
show your work

In my opinion, both these conditions are met. In fact, I would say this question is an excellent example of a good question. It showcases both these conditions and it also showcases a common misconception that a lot of students would benefit from.

I disagree. I don't see a specific concept being asked about in this post. Maybe you could pull out the mistake and pinpoint the error as a misunderstanding of some concept, but that is basically true of many "check my work" questions.

This question (my question, not the one I linked) is actually not really a question, but more a call to pay attention to behaviour like this. Physics stack exchange can be very unwelcoming to newcomers and closing questions unjustly is not only unwelcoming, but actively hinders the results that this site was built for. This question, that a lot of people can benefit from, can now no longer receive new answers with possible valuable insights. That's why I will vote to reopen.

I really understand this sentiment, and I do agree that there are cases of questions being closed way too quickly where it seems like there was not a lot of thought put into the decision, but the argument that we need to be careful about posts that many people can benefit from just doesn't hold up. There are plenty of useful questions that one could ask that should be closed based on the rules and guidelines of the site. Of course, no one should be unwelcoming in their interactions here, but posts should be judged based on their content and what is/isn't acceptable for a PSE post. Closure reasons have guidance to help improve a post, and users are still free to make posts and interact on the site.
